Translation of LINQ query with Intersect method fails in Entity Framework Core
Here i is the Store (entity) has given and Orders is a List<string> stored in Customers as the column type as jsonb. I need to fetch the i if any one of the request.Orders is matched with any one of the e.Orders.
query = query.Where(i => i.Customers != null 
                         && i.Customers.Any(e => e.Orders != null 
                         && e.Orders.Intersect(request.Orders).Any()));

I updated the above query as below. I am getting the data if I pass the data of two strings and these both must be contains in the record. but I need any one matches of the string matches with record must come
query = query.Where(i=>i.Customers!=null && i.Customers.Any(e=>EF.Functions.JsonContains(e.Orders,request.Orders));

The Intersect method is part of the System.Linq namespace and can be applied to any type implementing IEnumerable. When working with Complex Types (as in your case Orders), we should use the overloaded method which takes the IEqualityComparer parameter:
 Intersect<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>, IEqualityComparer<TSource>) 

In your case is applying the default comparer, used by the LINQ Intersect Method for comparison, and this one only checks whether two object references are equal and not the individual property values of the complex object.
Beside this usage problem the intersect  can't be translated into a SQL statement by the Entity Framework: Additional information: Translation of method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Intersect' failed..
You will have to rewrite the query.

What do you mean by complex types? Equality of elements depends on how the type is implemented it. Saying that it's always reference equality is just false.

OK, and what's your answer to the problem? So far all I see is documentation about the method and a reiteration of the error message. How about providing the rewritten  version of the query?

@JuanR How should I do it if I don't have the full code to use the IDs and so on? can u rewrite it? ... but it's easy to do a down vote. I have explained the problem and from here to use his IQ to move forward. Do you really think we should fix his code, maybe also to do some unit tests for him... anyway.... By the way he edited the question and we don't see the full error stack as it was initially

@DA If you don't have enough information, you can always ask for more details and even flag the question. None of this changes the fact that you did not post an answer that solves the problem. You merely paraphrased the documentation and the error message. That's why I downvoted it.
Your answer could start with the last sentence ("You will have to rewrite the query") followed by a version of the query that works with EF translation. That to me would be a valid answer.
